# How to make FlatButtons the same width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button

I have three *FlatButtons* widgets in a *Column* widget. The *FlatButtons* all have a *Text* widget as a child. The *Text* widgets show three different strings 'Sök på karta', 'Sök på betyg', 'Favoriter'. These string all have different lengths, which causes the size of the *FlatButtons* to differ.

The code below shows the current setup. The UI produced by this setup is attached in an image below as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hitta restaurang'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
              
                  FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Sök på betyg',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                  FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                      child: Text(
                        'Sök på karta',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                  FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Favoriter',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: UI output from the code]

Comment: Can you supply some more information about your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap you `FlatButton` widgets in `Container` widgets and set the width and height of the container. I have added a modification to your example code below:

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hitta restaurang'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Sök på betyg',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                onPressed: () {},
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                child: Text(
                  'Sök på karta',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Favoriter',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                )),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

This produces the following output:
[image: Output]